# How to let user fetch only those objects they are related to (by many-to-many relationship)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions, django-2.2

I have a project in which there are workspaces, and each workspace can have any number of users. Users can also belong to multiple workspaces, so there's a many-to-many relationship between them.

Now, I have workspace creation and membership working, but I'm having trouble setting the permissions so that only the workspace members can see the workspace. I've tried with a custom object-level permission, but it doesn't seem to work.

The workspace model looks like this:

```
class Workspace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='workspaces')
```

The view looks like this:

```
class WorkspaceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Workspace.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = WorkspaceSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated|BelongsInWorkspace]
```

The serializer is like this:

```
class WorkspaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Workspace
        fields = ('name', 'users')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super(WorkspaceSerializer, self)
        instance.users.add(self.context['request'].user)
        return instance
```

And finally, the custom permission I'm trying to use here:

```
class BelongsInWorkspace(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.users.filter(pk=request.user).exists()
```

Comment: `return request.user in obj.users.all()`

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to handle this problem. Django-guardian allows for straightforward, object-level permission management.

To handle your problem, all you would need to do is add a `Meta` class to your workspace model, where you can create custom permissions.

```
 class Workspace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='workspaces')

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ('add', 'change', 'delete')
        permissions = (
                ('access_workspace', 'Access workspace'),
                )
```

[Assign](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/assign.html#assign-obj-perms) either a user or a group that permission, attached to a specific workspace.

```
assign_perm('access_workspace', user, workspace)

#This will return True if the user has been properly assigned the permission
user.has_perm('access_workspace', workspace)
```

Then to get all workspaces a user has access to, you would just need to call [get_objects_for_user()](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/check.html#get-objects-for-user) in your view

```
queryset = get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, 'project.access_workspace')
```